# What is wrong with this cherry tree .. how to revive it?

Tags: plant-health

[image]

It has been so  from last  couple of months. 
Place:kashmir

Comment: My first thought is reaction to heat. What are the temperature conditions in Kashmir at the moment?

Comment: Well   around  25 °C   .

Comment: Then heat is probably NOT the problem. I think your tree might not have enough water. Maybe try to water it during dry periods.

Comment: Well there is enough water

Comment: Is it planted in the ground? When you say there is 'enough water' what does that mean? does it rain all the time? How long's this tree been planted?

Comment: Well the soil is moist  ..  there were rains  couple of times a week .  .   The plant was planted 2 years ago

Comment: If its in the ground, and you don't think its water shortage, check the stems and trunk  all over, right to the soil - you're looking for anything that shouldn't be there, like soft areas in the woody parts, or weeping or mould or rot

Comment: Its stem looks pretty well  .   . Totally lost in it..